# FALLO - Apliación desplegada en la ruta de contexto [/ValidacionForm], pero el contexto no pudo arrancar

Tags: java, spring

Estoy desarrollando recién en Spring y pues intento agregar un archivo.properties a mi configuración, eh investigado la forma de agregar un archivo y de esa forma lo estoy haciendo. 
mi proyecto carga normal SIN EL ARCHIVO.properties
pero cuando agrego el archivo me sale el siguiente error :

> FALLO - Apliación desplegada en la ruta de contexto [/ValidacionForm], pero el contexto no pudo arrancar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto no arranca cuando agrego la linea 20 en mi configuración pero si la quito el proyecto arranca con normalidad

- Este es mi Configuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Este es mi Configuración del Servlet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado almacenar tu archivo de propiedades bajo la carpeta de `/src/main/resources` y acceder a el con `@PropertySource( {"/PropiedadesValida.properties"} )`?

Comment: si, justamente lo puse ahí. creo que es por lo que estoy usando maven tenia que ponerle en esa ruta y salio. gracias por comentar!!.